# Shell script to return range(min and max) of date_time column of multiple data files

Tags: linux, shell, date, range

I have multiple data files, "|" separated, and I want to get the range of date column of all of them with a shell script(I am a newbie in shell programming). The data has no header.

Here is a row of my data, the date_time column in column 11.

```
2546|Sprint||0||0|0||4|0|2015-10-01 05:49:51
```

I have written a code but just getting gibberish results from it:

```
awk -F"[-,:. ]" '

BEGIN{

min_ext="99999999999999999999"

}
{
ext=$11$12$13$14$15$116$17; 
if(min_ext>ext){min_ext=ext}
if(max_ext<ext){max_ext=ext}
}


END{

print "min ext "min_ext
print "max ext "max_ext
}' data.csv
```

Comment: Given your field separator I can only see 6 fields ... I'm not surprised that aiming @ 11 and above gives odd results.

Comment: @tink There are empty fields there in between that makes date the 11th one

Comment: Not using your delimiters if there's no ` ` (space) in between `||`  ...

Comment: Plus you're still missing the pipe as a delimiter. **IF** you had that, `2015` would be your 11th field, that's true.  As it stands `2546|Sprint||0||0|0||4|0|2015` is your **first** field.

Comment: your internal logic is OK, Just use `awk -F'|' '{.....; ext=$11 ;....}` file. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't give us much data to work with ... :)
Made up input:

```
cat max
2546|Sprint||0||0|0||4|0|2015-10-02 05:49:51
2547|Sprint||0||0|0||4|0|2015-10-01 05:49:51
2548|Sprint||0||0|0||4|0|2015-10-06 05:49:51
```

Some output:

```
sort -t'|' -k11,11 max | awk 'NR==1;{last=$0}END{print last}' 
2547|Sprint||0||0|0||4|0|2015-10-01 05:49:51
2548|Sprint||0||0|0||4|0|2015-10-06 05:49:51
```

Edit 1: for giggles an awk-only solution:

```
awk -F'|' '{i[$11]=$0} END{c=asorti(i,o);print i[o[1]];print i[o[c]]}' max
2547|Sprint||0||0|0||4|0|2015-10-01 05:49:51
2548|Sprint||0||0|0||4|0|2015-10-06 05:49:51
```